# Physical significance of this operator in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I have stumbled across this question and cannot seem to find an answer to it.

Consider an operator $\textbf{A}$ with eigenkets $|{a_{i}\rangle}$ and distinct eigenvalues $a_{i}$ . One can check that the following operator is null:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i} (\textbf{A} - a_{i}).
\end{equation}

Now, given this, what is the physical significance of the following operator?

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i\neq j} \frac{(\textbf{A} - a_{i})}{(a_{j}-a_{i})}.
\end{equation}

I tried taking the spin-1/2 system and $\textbf{A} = S_{z}$ to see what's going on but it's still ultimately a null operator? I don't know where to look. Please help.

Comment: What is the context where you have encountered this operator. As you say it is basically an elaborate way to write $0$ (assuming $\mathbf{A}$ can be diagnosed), so I suspect that is all the physical significance you will find.

Comment: Makes sense now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your first formula is the l.h.s. of the *characteristic equation* of the matrix *A*.

The second one ***skips***  an index in the product, *j*, and so it is a function of *j*.
It is a projection on the eigenspace corresponding to $a_j$, called the
[Frobenius covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_covariant).
Those are essential in [Sylvester's formula for matrix functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula), usable for QM operators as well.

So, for instance, $$(\sigma_z-1\!\! 1)/(-2)=P_{-}$$ projects you to the spin-down state. Check that $P_- + P_+=1\!\! 1$.

I don't know what you'd mean by "physical significance". Projection operators are essential in the linear algebra of QM, where Sylvester's formula
$$  f(A) = \sum_{i=1}  f( a_i)  ~ P_i $$
is used routinely, albeit rarely labelled with that name.

Consider
$$
e^{i\theta \sigma_z/2}= e^{i\theta/2}P_+ + e^{-i\theta/2}P_-= \operatorname{diag} (e^{i\theta/2},e^{-i\theta/2}) \\
= \cos (\theta/2) ~1\!\! 1 + i\sin(\theta/2)~ \sigma_z .
$$

Comment: Just curious, is there an expansion akin to Sylvesters formula in case of degeneracies and when the operator is non diagonalizable without using Jordan form?

Comment: @Sunyam . Well, the WP article on Sylvester's formula gives the generalized case, but I am not familiar with it. Want to play around with a simple example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The generalized formula looks very ugly to remember, i was hoping for aesthetically pleasing one.

Comment: I wish I were expert in [defective matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix)...

Comment: The literature on functions of defective matrices for physicists seem very scattered. Couldn't locate any coherent presentation of key ideas for poor men.

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton!!!

Comment: Indeed, that's the idea...